# can java generics do what i am after?

Tags: java, generics, object

I have a question that i cant seem to find the answer to anywhere. I have two methods that are almost identical the difference between the two methods are that they are different objects.

```
public static **Object[]** readFile(**Object[]** inObj){
    for(int i = 0; i < inObj.length ; i++){
        inObj[i] = new **Object()**;
        String str = objectInput.nextLine();
        inObj[i].**setObjectLine**(str);
    }
    return inObj;
}
```

Above is an example of the method, some of it has been removed though. The bolded (encased in **) text are the parts that are different.
so i have two method exactly like this is it possible for me to use generics to eliminate the need for two different methods?

Comment: Do they share a common base interface with the method you need to call?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have control over your object classes, this is possible: Java has a specific idiom to support instantiation, and you should be able to add a common interface to support `setObjectLine` call.

```
interface WithSetLine {
    void setObjectLine(String str);
}
public static <T extends WithSetLine> T[] readFile(T[] inObj, Class<T> cl)
    throws Exception
{
    for(int i = 0; i < inObj.length ; i++) {
        inObj[i] = cl.newInstance();
        String str = objectInput.nextLine();
        inObj[i].setObjectLine(str);
    }
    return inObj;
}
```

Comment: The OP also might want to consider using a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) instead of using reflection.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i think it is all a little beyond my skill level though. Is there a way to determine the type of a method at run-time?

Comment: @user2899185 As far as I know, there is no easy way to determine the return type of the running method or its runtime parameters. You can do some hacking to do it, but that requires a lot higher skill level than the solution that I suggested. If you follow Oracle's introductory tutorial on generics, you should be able to understand every single line in the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Generics apply to classes and methods within those classes; it is confusing, at least, to talk about generics as they relate to methods alone.

If you have a class that has useful methods that would apply to different other classes, then you can use generics to define that class and instantiate objects of that class to deal with different parameter types.  You can think of an ArrayList, for instance, so that you could have a ArrayList and a ArrayList.  Then the various methods in list that require the class used to instantiate the array list apply to that passed-in class.

I hope that's a help.